# TextFlow in JavaFX does not show anything

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, textflow

I have created a UI for my application using "JavaFX Scene Builder".

I need to show text inside the TextFlow object so in my class (implements javafx.fxml.Initializable ) I write this

```
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)
{    
     Text t1 = new Text("My name is Josh!");
     tofl = new TextFlow(t1);
}
```

This way my TextFlow object does not show the Text at all.  Should I call a method on `tofl` like `tofl.apply()`to let the text appear?

TextFlow is initialized as a fieldabove the method, it is all linked with fxlm file too.
Using TextArea everything works fine instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are re-initializing your `TextFlow` to a new `TextFlow object`. You should never do that with fields linked with `@FXML`

If you want to add `Text` to the textFlow(defined in your FXML), use :

```
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)
{    
     Text t1 = new Text("My name is Josh!");
     tofl.getChildren().add(t1);
}
```